# Pandas: Renaming headers with identical names

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have several columns named the same (or not named at all, to be specific) in a dataframe. I need to rename them separately but df.rename method renames them altogether. For example, in a following df:

```
#     nan    nan    a    nan    nan    b    nan    nan
#     1       2     3     4      5     6     7      8
#     9      10     11    12    13     14    15     16
```

Following code changes all 'nan' headers into 'word':

```
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[1]:'word'})

#   word    word    a    word   word    b   word   word
#     1       2     3     4      5     6     7      8
#     9      10     11    12    13     14    15     16
```

How do I make it so that I can change the header names separately?
The ultimate goal for this example is to make the header look like the following:

```
#    nan     nan    a     a      a     b     b      b
#     1       2     3     4      5     6     7      8
#     9      10     11    12    13     14    15     16
```

Update: manual assignment of header values won't work in this case because this is a simplified version of my problem. I wouldn't know what the header values are and how many of them there are.

Following is a for loop that was supposed to incorporate the renaming method:

```
word = 'nan'
for i in range (0, len(list(df))-1):
if str(list(df)[i]) != 'nan':
    word = str(list(df)[i])
df.rename(columns={df.columns[i]:word})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df.columns = pd.Series(df.columns).mask(lambda x:x=='nan').ffill()
df

   NaN  NaN   a   a   a   b   b   b
0    1    2   3   4   5   6   7   8
1    9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply reset column names by this:

`df.columns = ["nan", "nan", "a", "a", "a", "b", "b", "b"]`

Comment: Thank you for your answer! But above is a simplified version of my problem, so I cannot rename the columns manually.I originally tried to use the for loop to iterate through the header column to detect the first non-nan column, then to convert the following nan columns into the first non-nan column's value, only to find out that such renaming doesn't work because of the problem asked.

Comment: @ZiaKim - then update your question with these requirements.

Comment: this is a hardcorded solution. It does not solve the problem

Comment: @onyambu - it did solve the problem as it was framed before the OP’s update

Comment: @jakub i saw the edit. It still did not solve the problem. Often the code should not be hardcoded

Answer (score 0):

### Change the n'th column of a pandas dataframe conditionally

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1, 2, 3], "nan": [4, 5, 6], "bar" : [7,8,9]}) 
print(df) 

thecolumns = list(df.columns)
if ( somecondition == True):
    thecolumns[1] = "newname" 
df.columns = thecolumns 
print(df)
```

Which prints:

```
   A  nan  bar
0  1    4    7
1  2    5    8
2  3    6    9

   A  newname  bar
0  1        4    7
1  2        5    8
2  3        6    9
```